# Managing tcp ports used by a component in service fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have a stateless service that has a Core Web API end point with http listener which is all good , however the service has some extra 3 party code that requires 2 tcp ports ( and has different startup behaviour)  , which causes obvious deployment issues. How can i tell service fabric that this port is used so it doesnt deploy to that node ?

The documentation seems to say instances will share the port eg "while replicas of a service running on the same node share the port" however this is not possible with tcp and would cause deployment issues.

Comment: I'd say it's a matter of declaring the 2 other ports as tcp [endpoints][1] in the service manifest. 
Did you try that?

  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-service-manifest-resources

Comment: That was my first thought but normally those ports require a Listener else it takes the node down.. Unfortunately there is no doco i can see of this relationship.

Comment: Did you try it? As an alternative, can you wrap the 3rd party code as a 'guest executable' and declare the endpoints?

Comment: I will try a guest executable but it will take some time , really looking for some docs.

Comment: According to the doco it will share the port this is not possible with tcp ports eg  "while replicas of a service running on the same node share the port".    Amending the question.